# Setting String Value in Intellij Debugger

Tags: json, debugging, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I can change string values which contains json data with copy/paste but in Intellij Idea when I paste json it gives **Invalid expresssion** error. I guess it needs an escaped value. Is there an easy way to change value of strings in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because IntelliJ doesn't expect a string content but a valid java expression.

Paste your json data inside an empty String. IntelliJ will automatically escape the characters :

1. Select your variable in the debugger
2. press F2
3. Type an empty String : `""`
4. Place your cursor inside the empty string and paste your json data
5. Press enter
6. Profit !